# $U(24) $ isomorphic to $Z_2\times Z_2 \times Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to show that $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$ is  isomorphic to $U(24)$.

I start by defining $f \colon Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2 \to U(24)$  by $f((a,b,c)) = 12a + 6b + 4c + 1 \pmod{24}$.

Let's attempt to show it preserves the operation:

$$ \begin{align*}
f((a,b,c))f((d,e,f)) &= 
(12a+6b+4c+ 1)(12d+6e+4f+1) \pmod{24} \\ &= 
144ad + 72ae + 48af + 12a + 72bd + 36be + 24bf + 6b \\ & \quad + 48cd + 24ec + 16cf + 4c + 12d + 6e + 4f + 1 \pmod{24} \\ &= 
12a + 12d + 6b + 6e + 4c + 4f + 1 + 36be + 16cf \pmod{24} \\ &= f((a+d,b+e,c+f)) + 36be + 16cf \pmod{24} \\ &= 
f((a,b,c)(d,e,f)) + 36be + 16cf \pmod{24}
\end{align*} $$

It seems like the extra $36be$ and $16cf$ terms are saying that $f$ does not preserve the operation...

However, I have been unable to find a counter example of the map not working (not a proof obviously, but I'm just wondering where I'm going wrong).

Comment: Is $U(24) = \mathbb{Z}_{24}^{\times}$ (the group of units in the ring of integers modulo 24)?

Comment: Your map $f$ is not well-defined.  For example, $(0,0,1) + (0,0,1) = (0,0,0) \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but $f(0,0,1) + f(0,0,1) = 5 + 5 = 10 \ne 1 = f(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Yes. Although we haven't learned about rings yet, it is the group of integers that have a multiplicative inverse mod 24.

Comment: @SammyBlack, the operation on $\Bbb U(24)$ is multiplication, not addition, so $5\cdot5=1$, as required.

Comment: @BrandonHathaway, maybe write out the group tables for each group and see if you can "see" an isomorphism. I wouldn't recommend going the formula route. Any chance you know anything about the classification of finite Abelian groups?

Comment: Right, so since U(24) has order 2^3 and it is abelian, it must be isomorphic to Z2 x Z2 x Z2. Edit: I guess I have to mention that it can't be isomorphic to Z4 x Z2 or Z8 since it has no elements with order greater then 2

Comment: I looked at your computation more closely.  There's a typo.  The term $16ef$ that appears after the first $=$ **should read** $16cf$, no?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Unfortunately I don't think this changes much. According to the algebra, it should not always preserve the operation, but when I try the numbers by hand, it seems to always work. It sure is making me curious though.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

- $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has order 8.
- Identify the 8 invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$.
- A homomorphism must map identity to identity.  Be careful here, since the group operation for $\mathbb{Z}_{24}^\times$ is multiplication but addition in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.
- Start multiplying some of the invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$, to try to see an isomorphism.

Comment: I know that each element in U(24) has order 2, and clearly the elements of Z2 x Z2 x Z2 do aswell. Also, the identity of Z2 x Z2 x Z2 is (0,0,0) and the identity of U(24) is 1. 
My mapping does indeed map (0,0,0) to 1.

Comment: You've found one generator.  Now, find two more.  See how they multiply together.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, here's the rub.  The variables $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.  So, for example, the "error" term $36be$ is $0$ unless both $b = e = 1$, but in that case, $b + e = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Concretely, we have

$$\begin{align}
f((0,1,0))f((0,1,0)) &= (6 + 1)(6 + 1) = 36 + 6 + 6 + 1 = 49 = 1 \\
\text{and }f((0,1,0)+(0,1,0)) &= f(0,0,0) = 1,
\end{align}$$

as expected.  However, without reducing modulo $2$ before applying the function, we get

$$ f((0,1,0)+(0,1,0)) = f((0,2,0)) = 12 + 1 = 13,$$

and only after adding $36be = 36$ do we recover the correct value of 1.

Your function is not well-defined.

---

Here's a map that is a homomorphism:

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 &\to \mathbb{Z}_{24}^\times \\
(a, b, c) &\mapsto 13^a \cdot 7^b \cdot 5^c
\end{align}
$$

Notice that it gives the same values as your $f$, but it has the expected *exponential* behavior, converting additive structure to multiplicative structure.

Answer (score 0):

For odd $n$ that are not a multiple of 3, one of $n-1$ and $n+1$ is divisible by 4 and the other is divisible by 2. Also, one of $n-1$ and $n+1$ is divisible by three.

So, for odd $n$ that are not a multiple of 3, $n^2-1$ is a multiple of 24.

If $x$ is invertible mod 24, $x$ must be odd and not a multiple of three. There are $\phi(24) = \phi(8 \times 3) = 8$ such $x$.

Therefore, $U(24)$ is a group of 8 elements, in which every element has order 2. Thus $U(24) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2^3$ by elementary group theory.