# Writing group tables using formula??

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am sorry for asking, but on searching for group table of $U_{24}$ came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344542/u24-isomorphic-to-z-2-times-z-2-times-z-2) answer, with no hint except in a comment (by @Dylan Yott) to it that states some reference to formula for writing the multiplication table.

If given some sort of initiation into this, as am unable to google by any term as :"multiplication table of group generated by formula". Is it a sort of generating function based approach? It is my wild guess, but only that fits the formula approach for permutations.

*Addendum* A very good book [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XUHeJVdl0IUC&pg=PA52&dq=generating%20function%20formula%20for%20writing%20group%20multiplication%20table&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ6I_s4tjYAhVIUZQKHf-bCnYQ6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=generating%20function%20formula%20for%20writing%20group%20multiplication%20table&f=false) (Combinatorial Organic Chemistry: An Educational Approach By Sherif El-Basil), but the lack of first 14 pages make a novice like me to be unable to understand. Although, it is abound with this type only.

Is there a source available for free, that allows one to understand.

Comment: Are you asking where the formula for the isomorphism in the linked question came from? (If so, the answer is presumably the Chinese Remainder Theorem.)

Comment: @anon Yes, the starting point where it is stated :"I start by defining $f \colon Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2 \to U(24)$  by $f((a,b,c)) = 12a + 6b + 4c + 1 \pmod{24}$." It is not clear at all how the formula occurs in the first place.

Comment: @anon Do you feel that I should be able to proceed from your comment. Please indicate, if so.

Comment: I wish there were more detailed answer that were not mere rewording of my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344542/u24-isomorphic-to-z-2-times-z-2-times-z-2):

> I'm trying to show that $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$ is  isomorphic to $U(24)$.
>
> I start by defining $f \colon Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2 \to U(24)$  by $f((a,b,c)) = 12a + 6b + 4c + 1 \pmod{24}$.

The OP is trying to show that two groups are isomorphic, and uses a formula to propose what they hope is an isomorphism; a function taking elements of one group to another (with other properties).

[The comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344542/u24-isomorphic-to-z-2-times-z-2-times-z-2#comment740438_344542) in question:

> [M]aybe write out the group tables for each group and see if you can "see" an isomorphism. I wouldn't recommend going the formula route. Any chance you know anything about the classification of finite Abelian groups?

This comment is suggesting that, instead of trying to define an isomorphism by writing out a formula (as OP has attempted), they instead look at the multiplication tables (or, "Cayley tables") of the two groups in question. I assume the commenter hopes that "structural similarities" would be evident to the OP, when comparing the two multiplication tables, and that these similarities could be used in the quest for isomorphism.

So, the formula (which, presumably, doesn't work and consequently wouldn't be likely to help you understand either group) is one thing, and a multiplication table is another. The two aren't related, at least in this instance.

If you want to create a multiplication table for either group, I wouldn't expect any sort of formula to help (other than formulas defining the group operation). *Note*: for some groups, one may well find formulas that help in writing down a multiplication table ([dihedral groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Group_structure), for instance; see the last few lines in the linked section) but I wouldn't expect such a thing here.

Comment: I google out, and found a very good book as shown in my edited OP, but as the first 14 pages are not there in the Google books, so unable to understand.

Comment: Please comment on my edited OP.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure exactly what you *are* looking for -- only that this probably isn't it :)

Comment: I request you t elaborate what you mean by the reference: "this probably isn't it", if you mean by that the 'book' stated in my edited OP,  then totally confused.